# Additional arguments for functions assigned to variables in Javascript closures

Tags: javascript, function, variables, closures

I’m reading Eloquent JS and looking for clarification on this piece of code:

```js
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function(number) {
    return number * factor;
  }; 
}

var twice = multiplier(2); 
console.log(twice(5)); 
// → 10
```

I understand the closure concept but what I’m stuck on is the way `twice(5)` is called in the last line. Eloquent JS says:

"In the example, multiplier returns a frozen chunk of code that gets stored in the twice variable. The last line then calls the value in this variable, causing the frozen code (return number * factor;) to be activated. It still has access to the factor variable from the multiplier call that created it, and in addition it gets access to the argument passed when unfreezing it, 5, through its number parameter.”

Is the "additional access" to the argument `5` passed when unfreezing a feature of closures? How does this work when twice is a variable?

Comment: The only thing that is returned is what is inside function's curly brackets after return keyword.

Comment: @Kunok, not only. it has access to `factor`, too.

Comment: Yes, it returns expression:  `number * factor`. You can look at it as a single thing because once it is executed, it is a single value, a result of expression.

Comment: Yes its a a feature of closures. Closures have access to the outer function’s variable even after the outer function returns. When functions in JavaScript execute, they use the same scope chain that was in effect when they were created. This means that even after the outer function has returned, the inner function still has access to the outer function’s variables. Therefore, you can call the inner function later in your program. In this case “twice” function variable has access to outer function “multiplier” 'factor' variable, which is feature of closure.

Comment: I don't know this book, but the terms "frozen" and "activated" seem confusing and non-standard. `multiplier` simply returns a **function** when called; there's no need to call it a "frozen chunk of code". When that function is in turn called (with `twice(5)`) there's no reason to say it's "activated"; there are perfectly good terms for that, such as "executed", or "invoked", or "run".

Comment: Thanks so much @user3350003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you name the inner function and inspect in devtools it should make more sense.

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function innerMultiplier(number) {
    return number * factor;
  }
}
```

when assigning to twice multiplier is called returning the inner function
because javascript has first class function they can be passed around and
assigned to variables by reference

```
var twice = multiplier(2)
```

now `innerMultiplier` is assigned to the `twice` variable, but it's still a function that can be called.

when you run `twice(5)` you are calling `innerMultiplier` with `factor` locked into it's closure

This is what is refereed to as **currying** or **partial application**

Comment: This is just currying, not partial application. Partial application makes only sense in the context of multi-argument function like `const mul = (x, y) => x * y`.

Comment: Naming the inner function helps a lot. Thanks @synthet1c.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about this syntax at first as well, but don't fear!
the 'twice' variable was just assigned to a special type of function called a closure, it has access to the containing function's scope, global scope, and it's own variables. But I don't think that is the actual root of the confusion, it is just how you are calling the closure.

To get a better understanding, I would simply console.log() your "twice" variable. You will see that it looks just like a normal function:

```
function (number) { 
       return number * factor;
}
```

Like I touched upon above, twice(2) would return 4 because "factor" is in the containing scope, which happen to be the multiplier function, and has a value of 2. In your question, the twice variable is actually not necessary at all

```
console.log(multiplier(2)(2));
```

Hopefully that helps clear things up!

Comment: Thanks so much @splay. This helps a lot.